# ServiceBus default concurrent number

Tags: azureservicebus

I just check the ServiceBus method for receive message, it show two way can do that:

```
 void RegisterMessageHandler(Func<Message, CancellationToken, Task> handler, Func<ExceptionReceivedEventArgs, Task> exceptionReceivedHandler);
 void RegisterMessageHandler(Func<Message, CancellationToken, Task> handler, MessageHandlerOptions messageHandlerOptions);
```

I find `MessageHandlerOptions` has field for setting MaxConcurrent calls. But I want to know if I choose the first method without `MessageHandlerOptions`, what is the default concurrent calls to set.

And if I want to use `MessageHandlerOptions` and set maxconcurrent to a big number not limit calls. What is the number I should set?

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls` is one.

`MaxConcurrentCalls` is not the only setting to improve throughput. This article can help: [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging article prior to getting into performance optimizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements).